# WPF can't remove a file

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code:

```
imgScreenshot.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ShellFolder.DocumentsFolder() + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + screenshot.Filename));
File.Delete(ShellFolder.DocumentsFolder() + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + screenshot.Filename);
```

I get an error:

> {"The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\rover\Documents\MagicScreenshot\vEhWg3Ra20M.jpg' because it is being used by another process."}

I thought about dispose BitmapImage, but this class does not realize this interface. How to write this code correctly?

Comment: Try putting the code to delete the file in the event handler for the [`DownloadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadcompleted.aspx)  event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.UriSource = new Uri(ShellFolder.DocumentsFolder() + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + screenshot.Filename);
        bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bi.EndInit();
        imgScreenshot.Source = bi;
        File.Delete(ShellFolder.DocumentsFolder() + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + screenshot.Filename);
```